# Create multiple archives from a directory without the directory root name being added to the archive

Tags: command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip

This batch works fine for creating multiple archives in a folder but adds the root folder to the archive. I would like it to only add the files inside the root.
This is the code I have:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use just a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop omitting the `/d` parameter and it will work just as you describe creating the zip archive file(s) and not contain its parent folder.

> ### Commands
>
> **Note:** *This will add a zip archive file for each file in the directory with only that file in the zip.*
>
> ```
> for %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~X.zip" "%%~X"
> ```
>
> **Note:** *This will add all files only in the directory to the one zip file you specify.*
>
> ```
> for %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "<MyZipFileName>.zip" "%%~X"
> ```

---

> ### Nest Loop Command
>
> **Note:** *This will add files only from the directories beneath the directory which the batch file resides to a zip file matching the name of the directory.*
>
> ```
> @ECHO ON
>
> FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A in ('DIR /S /B /AD "*"') DO (
>   FOR %%B IN (*) DO (
>       "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~fA.zip" "%%~fA\*")
> )
> EXIT
> ```

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  > ```
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [a (Add) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't quite do what I need. The batch needs to zip multiple folders for example there is a main folder that contains the batch and all the folders that need to be separately zipped. My current code can zip all the files but for example, it zips each folder also so when I open zip I get foldername/contents where all I want when I open the zip is the contents. Sorry if my explanation is vague.

Comment: @nead2ether Look over the new section I added labeled "**Nest Loop Command**" as well as the additional resource in the "**Further Resources**" section that from what I tested, does exactly what you need per your clarification.