# Batch file to copy folder to all users network home directory

Tags: windows, batch, robocopy

I'm looking to create a batch file copy a folder from `\\server\folder\subdirectory` to `\\server\users\username\folder`.  I don't want to have hundreds of lines for all the users.  I there a simpler wild card or variable I can use.

I have this so far and it works if I input each username one by one.

```
robocopy "\\server\folder\subdirectory" "\\server\users\%username%\folder" /e /v /dcopy:t /copy:dat /r:1 /w:1 /A-:SHA /XA:H
copy "\\server\folder\subdirectory\*.docx" "\\server\users\%username%\folder2"
```

Comment: A nested `FOR` loop comes to my mind using `delims` and `tokens` accordingly to set the variable for the `<username>` with a `dir /b` command perhaps, and then use that variable in the Robocopy command. I'm sure I've written such scripts here before if you poke around you should be able to find something to do more testing. This is just a guess but I'm short on time at the moment but that's my feedback at least. Here's a quick example but adjust accordingly and test thoroughly for your needs. The `delims` and `tokens` will be different too.

Comment: Here's an example post of this sort of solution.... https://superuser.com/questions/1312356/create-multiple-archives-from-a-directory-without-the-directory-root-name-being/1312430#1312430

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided I believe this is the simplest method of accomplishing what you want:

```
@echo off

set "src=\\server\folder\subdirectory"
set "des=\\server\users"

for /d %%A in (%des%\*) do (
    robocopy "%src%" "%%A\folder" /e
    copy "%src%\*.docx" "%%A\folder2"
)
```

I like using variables to reduce the amount of things you need to change and to make lines that would potentially be full of paths a bit easier to digest. Above you will see I set variables for both your source (`src`) and destination (`des`) paths, and used those in a simple for loop.

For any subfolders of the destination (`/d in %des%\*`) assign them to our parameter `%%A`, then use that parameter in both your robocopy and copy scripts. You'll see I didn't include all of your robocopy flags, but that was to make the example as simple as possible. Hopefully this works out for you or whoever else stumbles upon this question.